Why does PostgreSQL accept connections during recovery?
Why does PostgreSQL accept connections during recovery?
I wanted to use ps_isready to determine if my database is done recovering from a backup and ready to accept connections. But it says the database is ready long before it is actually done recovering.
I now check if the recovery.signal file exists, but I wonder if there is a "better" way to determine if it is done recovering.

Two options come to my mind:

connect and check if PostgreSQL is no longer in recovery mode:
psql -Atq -c 'SELECT pg_is_in_recovery()'


if the connection fails, PostgreSQL isn't up

if the result is t, PostgreSQL is recovering

if the result is f, PostgreSQL is done with recovery.



set hot_standby = off in postgresql.conf
Then PostgreSQL won't allow connections in recovery mode.


